# pagesize and linesize standards for different screen resolutions %window

Tags: window, sas, resolution

I wrote a very powerful program that allows user interaction with the %window function in SAS.

Now, it works great, I'm so happy with the results that I reached. But when I sent this program to some users that are supposed to run it, they found out that not all the text is promped in the output-Window.
After some tries I found out that my program was intended to run under my pc resolution 1280x1024 (not-so-good) and my linesize and pagesize standard options.

These other users are using systems with different resolutions, for example one of them is using a laptop with 1366x768, and he is obviosly seeing a portion of the window cutted from its content.
Even if she tried to set my linesize and pagesize (I got mine using %put %sysfunc(getoption(linesize));) she still not see the entire window.

How can I handle this kind of issue? How can I find some documentation on different output size for each different resolution?

I know that I'm supposed to post some code tries, but this is not a code request here, but I don't think that this question is completely code-related. Maybe one of you ever had some experience with this.

Thank you.

EDIT: I'd like to use SAS-AF but I don't have a licence for it.

```
SAMPLE WINDOW CODE:
%macro windows();
        %window thiswindow

                #2 @5 "/-----------------------------------------------------------------------------\"
                #3 @5 "|------------------xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-------------------|"
                #4 @5 "|------------------------------------------------------------xxxxxxxxxxxxxx---|"
                #5 @5 "| xxxxxxxxxxx"
                #5 @83 "|"
                #6 @5 "| xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                #6 @83 "|"
                #7 @5 "| xxxxxx"
                #7 @45 "  xxxxxxxxxxxx"
                #7 @83 "|"
                #8 @5 "\-----------------------------------------------------------------------------/"

                #10 @2  "001"               
                #10 @7 "&macrovar1"
                #10 @45 "041"
                #10 @50 "&macrovar41"
                #10 @88 "081"
                #10 @93 "&macrovar81"

                #11 @2  "002"
                #11 @7 "&macrovar2"
                #11 @45 "042"
                #11 @50 "&macrovar42"
                #11 @88 "082"
                #11 @93 "&macrovar82"

                #12 @2  "003"
                #12 @7 "&macrovar3"
                #12 @45 "043"
                #12 @50 "&macrovar43"
                #12 @88 "083"
                #12 @93 "&macrovar83"

                #13 @2  "004"
                #13 @7 "&macrovar4"
                #13 @45 "044"
                #13 @50 "&macrovar44"
                #13 @88 "084"
                #13 @93 "&macrovar84"

                #14 @2  "005"
                #14 @7 "&macrovar5"
                #14 @45 "045"
                #14 @50 "&macrovar45"
                #14 @88 "085"
                #14 @93 "&macrovar85"

                #15 @2  "006"
                #15 @7 "&macrovar6"
                #15 @45 "046"
                #15 @50 "&macrovar46"
                #15 @88 "086"
                #15 @93 "&macrovar86"

                #16 @2  "007"
                #16 @7 "&macrovar7"
                #16 @45 "047"
                #16 @50 "&macrovar47"
                #16 @88 "087"
                #16 @93 "&macrovar87"

                #17 @2  "008"
                #17 @7 "&macrovar8"
                #17 @45 "048"
                #17 @50 "&macrovar48"
                #17 @88 "088"
                #17 @93 "&macrovar88"

                #18 @2  "009"
                #18 @7 "&macrovar9"
                #18 @45 "049"
                #18 @50 "&macrovar49"
                #18 @88 "089"
                #18 @93 "&macrovar89"

                #19 @2  "010"
                #19 @7 "&macrovar10"
                #19 @45 "050"
                #19 @50 "&macrovar50"
                #19 @88 "090"
                #19 @93 "&macrovar90"

                #20 @2  "011"
                #20 @7 "&macrovar11"
                #20 @45 "051"
                #20 @50 "&macrovar51"
                #20 @88 "091"
                #20 @93 "&macrovar91"

                #21 @2  "012"
                #21 @7 "&macrovar12"
                #21 @45 "052"
                #21 @50 "&macrovar52"
                #21 @88 "092"
                #21 @93 "&macrovar92"

                #22 @2  "013"
                #22 @7 "&macrovar13"
                #22 @45 "053"
                #22 @50 "&macrovar53"
                #22 @88 "093"
                #22 @93 "&macrovar93"

                #23 @2  "014"
                #23 @7 "&macrovar14"
                #23 @45 "054"
                #23 @50 "&macrovar54"
                #23 @88 "094"
                #23 @93 "&macrovar94"

                #24 @2  "015"
                #24 @7 "&macrovar15"
                #24 @45 "055"
                #24 @50 "&macrovar55"
                #24 @88 "095"
                #24 @93 "&macrovar95"

                #25 @2  "016"
                #25 @7 "&macrovar16"
                #25 @45 "056"
                #25 @50 "&macrovar56"
                #25 @88 "096"
                #25 @93 "&macrovar96"

                #26 @2  "017"
                #26 @7 "&macrovar17"
                #26 @45 "057"
                #26 @50 "&macrovar57"
                #26 @88 "097"
                #26 @93 "&macrovar97"

                #27 @2  "018"
                #27 @7 "&macrovar18"
                #27 @45 "058"
                #27 @50 "&macrovar58"
                #27 @88 "098"
                #27 @93 "&macrovar98"

                #28 @2  "019"
                #28 @7 "&macrovar19"
                #28 @45 "059"
                #28 @50 "&macrovar59"
                #28 @88 "099"
                #28 @93 "&macrovar99"

                #29 @2  "020"
                #29 @7 "&macrovar20"
                #29 @45 "060"
                #29 @50 "&macrovar60"
                #29 @88 "100"
                #29 @93 "&macrovar100"

                #30 @2  "021"
                #30 @7 "&macrovar21"
                #30 @45 "061"
                #30 @50 "&macrovar61"
                #30 @88 "101"
                #30 @93 "&macrovar101"

                #31 @2  "022"
                #31 @7 "&macrovar22"
                #31 @45 "062"
                #31 @50 "&macrovar62"
                #31 @88 "102"
                #31 @93 "&macrovar102"

                #32 @2  "023"
                #32 @7 "&macrovar23"
                #32 @45 "063"
                #32 @50 "&macrovar63"
                #32 @88 "103"
                #32 @93 "&macrovar103"

                #33 @2  "024"
                #33 @7 "&macrovar24"
                #33 @45 "064"
                #33 @50 "&macrovar64"
                #33 @88 "104"
                #33 @93 "&macrovar104"

                #34 @2  "025"
                #34 @7 "&macrovar25"
                #34 @45 "065"
                #34 @50 "&macrovar65"
                #34 @88 "105"
                #34 @93 "&macrovar105"

                #35 @2  "026"
                #35 @7 "&macrovar26"
                #35 @45 "066"
                #35 @50 "&macrovar66"
                #35 @88 "106"
                #35 @93 "&macrovar106"

                #36 @2  "027"
                #36 @7 "&macrovar27"
                #36 @45 "067"
                #36 @50 "&macrovar67"
                #36 @88 "107"
                #36 @93 "&macrovar107"

                #37 @2  "028"
                #37 @7 "&macrovar28"
                #37 @45 "068"
                #37 @50 "&macrovar68"
                #37 @88 "108"
                #37 @93 "&macrovar108"

                #38 @2  "029"
                #38 @7 "&macrovar29"
                #38 @45 "069"
                #38 @50 "&macrovar69"
                #38 @88 "109"
                #38 @93 "&macrovar109"

                #39 @2  "030"
                #39 @7 "&macrovar30"
                #39 @45 "070"
                #39 @50 "&macrovar70"
                #39 @88 "110"
                #39 @93 "&macrovar110"

                #40 @2  "031"
                #40 @7 "&macrovar31"
                #40 @45 "071"
                #40 @50 "&macrovar71"
                #40 @88 "111"
                #40 @93 "&macrovar111"

                #41 @2  "032"
                #41 @7 "&macrovar32"
                #41 @45 "072"
                #41 @50 "&macrovar72"
                #41 @88 "112"
                #41 @93 "&macrovar112"

                #42 @2  "033"
                #42 @7 "&macrovar33"
                #42 @45 "073"
                #42 @50 "&macrovar73"
                #42 @88 "113"
                #42 @93 "&macrovar113"

                #43 @2  "034"
                #43 @7 "&macrovar34"
                #43 @45 "074"
                #43 @50 "&macrovar74"
                #43 @88 "114"
                #43 @93 "&macrovar114"

                #44 @2  "035"
                #44 @7 "&macrovar35"
                #44 @45 "075"
                #44 @50 "&macrovar75"
                #44 @88 "115"
                #44 @93 "&macrovar115"

                #45 @2  "036"
                #45 @7 "&macrovar36"
                #45 @45 "076"
                #45 @50 "&macrovar76"
                #45 @88 "116"
                #45 @93 "&macrovar116"

                #46 @2  "037"
                #46 @7 "&macrovar37"
                #46 @45 "077"
                #46 @50 "&macrovar77"
                #46 @88 "117"
                #46 @93 "&macrovar117"

                #47 @2  "038"
                #47 @7 "&macrovar38"
                #47 @45 "078"
                #47 @50 "&macrovar78"
                #47 @88 "118"
                #47 @93 "&macrovar118"

                #48 @2  "039"
                #48 @7 "&macrovar39"
                #48 @45 "079"
                #48 @50 "&macrovar79"
                #48 @88 "119"
                #48 @93 "&macrovar119"

                #49 @2  "040"
                #49 @7 "&macrovar40"
                #49 @45 "080"
                #49 @50 "&macrovar80"
                #49 @88 "120"
                #49 @93 "&macrovar120"


                #52 @5 "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                #53 @5 "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                #54 @5 "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

                #55 @5 ncoded 80 attr=underline;
%mend;
```

Then I fill each macro variable stepwise with the first 120 observations of a dataset using:

```
%let rc= %sysfunc(open(dataset));
%let nobs= %sysfunc(attrn(&rc.,nlobs));
%let cl= %sysfunc(close(&rc.)); 
%syscall(set(dataset)); 
%do i=1 %to &nobs;
%let fetcher= %sysfunc(fetchobs(dataset,&i.));
%let macrovar&i.=&variable.;
%end;
```

anyway if you only need to reproduce this situation you can run this code:

```
%macro a();
%do i=1 %to 120;
%let macrovar&i.= this_is_the_&i._macrovar;
%end;
%windows();
%mend a; %a();
```

And I display the window filled with all the observations with this sample code:

```
data _null_;
%display thiswindow;
run;
```

Now, with my pc with resolution 1280x1024, the window is displayed correctly, but with another resolution, for example with a laptop of 1366x768, I display something truncated like this:

[image: this is the truncated sample]

Comment: Can you write an example %window program that has this problem, and perhaps a picture of the problem?

Comment: LINESIZE and PAGESIZE are just for fixed font listing output. Your issue is the interaction between the users default font  size and their screen resolution.

Comment: @Joe , sample code and picture added. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The number of ROWS and COLUMNS that will fit in the window depends on the font used and the terminal resolution.  You can find/change the font used with the FONT option.

```
%let save=%sysfunc(getoption(font));
options font=(Sasfont 8) ;
%window ...
...
options font=&save ;
```

But I am not sure how you can find the size of the window or screen. I would recommend just agreeing on size that works for all of your normal users.

Comment: Thank you Tom for the try, but it seems that I already set that opt to the minimum font size (Sasfont 8). So this solution won't work for me, I need something that could actually change the terminal resolution or adapt the output window according to a standard given specification. Otherwise something like an "algorithm" to derive which is the number of maximum character shown in the output window, by row and by column, with the minimum font (Sasfont 8) can be useful.
It seems that the window is simply built by tiles, but the number of rows and columns changes with the resolution. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm marking this answer as useful, it clearly helped us to reach the solution, many thanks, but I'm not marking this as correct, maybe there will be a real solution to this :)

Comment: Why not ask the user?  You could display a grid with two input fields and ask the user to tell you how many columns and rows they can actually see.

Comment: Because I wanted to find a global solution, not one designed ad hoc for each possible user...

Comment: When you are building a house using just a hatchet you have to make some compromises. :)